# Is there an up-to-date VLC PPA for 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, ppa, vlc

I'm looking for updated VLC builds for Lucid.

I was using c-korn, but it's gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PPA installable by `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/vlc` has been set up due to the demise of c-korn and contains 1.1.4 currently. (Maverick contains 1.1.3 at present.)

For your information and future reference I found this by going to the [Launchpad vlc Ubuntu package page](http://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vlc) and clicking on "Other versions of 'vlc' in untrusted archives".

Reference: [How to use PPAs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: +1 for teaching him how to fish in addition to giving him something to eat. :)

Comment: Well, I currently have 1.1.2 so I'll probably have to wait a little longer to get updates. I keep an eye on the "Other versions" section. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm it looks like that hint I gave you for searching isn't showing all PPAs unfortunately... (time to go file a bug)

For instance the PPA installable by `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/vlc` (contains 1.1.4) mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: I'v added this ppa to my 10.04 but I'm not able to have a different version of vlc, sudo apt-get install vlc give always 1.0.6.

Answer (score 2):

This link will give you a PPA that has VLC 1.1.4. I installed from here and have had no problems.

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/08/install-vlc-114-in-ubuntu-via-new-ppa.html